# Visual Studio 14 vnext EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build the latest EntityFramework 7 from github.  To accomplish this I have a clean VM from azure for CTP 4.  I cloned the repository, brought up a cmd prompt typed build initialize.  It restores the packages.  I then type build and it crashes with the same stack trace all the time provided here:

```
Resolving complete, 211ms elapsed
Restore complete, 212ms elapsed
Total time 4598ms
warn: Exit code 1 from cmd
verbose: Stack trace:
   at View694f03af3b524c7ea66d760ec81769f4.<RenderViewLevel0>b__38() in c:\Users
\kkoenig\AppData\Local\Temp\2\fdbe9ba6df31456eaaec2d06ea5d690a-1.cs:line 1649
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.StartingTarget(String name)
   at View694f03af3b524c7ea66d760ec81769f4.<RenderViewLevel0>b__2b() in c:\Users
\kkoenig\AppData\Local\Temp\2\fdbe9ba6df31456eaaec2d06ea5d690a-1.cs:line 1252
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.StartingTarget(String name)
   at View694f03af3b524c7ea66d760ec81769f4.<RenderViewLevel0>b__2c() in c:\Users
\kkoenig\AppData\Local\Temp\2\fdbe9ba6df31456eaaec2d06ea5d690a-1.cs:line 1269
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.StartingTarget(String name)
   at View694f03af3b524c7ea66d760ec81769f4.<RenderViewLevel0>b__2d() in c:\Users
\kkoenig\AppData\Local\Temp\2\fdbe9ba6df31456eaaec2d06ea5d690a-1.cs:line 1286
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.StartingTarget(String name)
   at View694f03af3b524c7ea66d760ec81769f4.<RenderViewLevel0>b__2e() in c:\Users
\kkoenig\AppData\Local\Temp\2\fdbe9ba6df31456eaaec2d06ea5d690a-1.cs:line 1303
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)
   at View694f03af3b524c7ea66d760ec81769f4.<RenderViewLevel0>b__26() in c:\Users
\kkoenig\AppData\Local\Temp\2\fdbe9ba6df31456eaaec2d06ea5d690a-1.cs:line 1159
   at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)
   at Sake.Engine.SakeEngine.Execute(Options options)
 at Sake.Engine.SakeEngine.Execute(String[] args)
       at Sake.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Another sign that something is wrong is, when I open the EntityFramework project in VisualStudio 14 CTP 4 and look at the references in the EntityFramework project under src it has a yellow triangle and no dependencies are listed.

Comment: Does the VM you are using have the Prerequisites installed? They are listed here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Getting-and-Building-the-Code#prerequisites

Comment: I believe so.  I have kvm installed as documented.  I have a clean vs 14 vm from azure (this is my third go around).  I have the cloned repository.  So I am not sure what else to do

Comment: Okay. Seems some tests fail for me on the dev branch of EF7 with a similar (but a lot longer) stack trace, scroll up in your command prompt and see. Also check if the build put some artifacts in "..EntityFramework\artifacts\build". The tests run after the build outputs the nuget packages.

Comment: there are no artifacts.  I don't think it is really building.  I think the build process is crashing for some reason...but I am not sure

Comment: [Sake](https://github.com/loudej/sake) errors are useless... You probably need to install [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) and [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579).

Comment: Also try changing the "R" on [test/EntityFramework.Redis.FunctionalTests/project.json line 6](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/test/EntityFramework.Redis.FunctionalTests/project.json#L6) to lowercase.

Comment: Will do.  And let you know.